# How can I keep things aligned while supporting all device screens?

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: none;
            margin-top: 0;
     nargin-right: 0;
            padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
        }
        #cbox {
            border: 1px black solid;
            width: 99.0%;
            height: 89.0%;
            padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
        .message {
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 98.9%;
            border: 1px black solid;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
        #snd-msg {
            width: 97%;
            height: calc(4% +50px);
            overflow: hidden;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
        .pimg {
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
            border: 1px black dashed;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .date {
            _float: right;
            float: right;
            color: gray;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 8px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .title {
     height: 150px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 5px;
     font-size: 10px;
        }
 .ctext { font-family: monospace; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 600; color: blue; float: right; _float: right; margin-right: 18px;}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<div class="container">
    <span class="title" id="title">Room Title</span>
    <div id="cbox">
    <div class="message">
    <img class="pimg" src="https://otku.ga/images/tink.jpg"><span class="date">7/28/2017 - 4:0:34</span><span><span class="username" style="">tink</span><span class="text" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: monospace;">Donec orci metus, tempor et luctus ut, convallis non dui. Quisque mattis quis nulla quis laoreet. Morbi rutrum diam tellus, in volutpat nunc facilisis vitae. Nullam vitae ornare est, non congue turpis. Donec vel vehicula dolor, ut commodo enim. Donec sollicitudin nisi mi, vel facilisis quam aliquet faucibus. Vivamus venenatis laoreet lacus, ornare elementum nisl eleifend et. Fusce viverra vel purus quis ultricies. Nunc tempus dignissim ligula et condimentum. In ut dignissim urna, nec feugiat mi. Maecenas rutrum ipsum eget lacus suscipit, sit amet interdum nibh placerat. </span></span>
    </div>
<span class="ctext">People: <span id="count">0</span></span>
<input type="text" id="snd-msg" placeholder="Enter a message.." />
</div>
```

For the life for the life of me I can't figure out how to fix this. What I'm trying to do is make this chat totally responsive. But, as you can see its a little bit hard, I want to cut off the message at 150px max keeping everything aligned an example of what everything looking correct is here https://otku.ga/chat.html?room=examplegroup

Comment: Change some css and html part check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height:50px; under .message class style.
and for every screen resolution you have to use media queries
visit : https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/media-queries-responsive-web-design/